# Why does a simple .Net Core 3.0 WPF app not start on a deployment computer

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

Created very simple WPF .Net Core app with VS2019Prof V16.3.1.

- Created new project - WPF App (.Net Core)
- Nothing else was done, just only built the project (Debug and Release) - successfully run it on 'dev' computer Win10 V1809 (Build 17763.740)
- Copied debug and release folder to 'client' computer Win10 V1809 (Build 17763.740)
- Installed .Net Core 3.0 Desktop Runtime on 'client' computer
- rebooted client computer
- tried to run debug and release version

Just no reaction when starting the app. 
... tried to observe anything with SysInternals ProcessExplorer, it starts and immediately stop. No crash message, ... nothing...

What else could I do to narrow down the reason why it doesn't start?

[image: Compile result]

Comment: Tried running it in console? Maybe through dotnet command? Also, I believe you need to publish the application. Just building it is not enough. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21

Comment: More details on publishing : https://www.telerik.com/blogs/3-ways-to-deploy-a-winforms-or-wpf-net-core-application

Comment: After installing **.Net Core SDK**  instead of **desktop runtime** on the client computer, all my .Net Core programs are starting now... seems that there is something missing in the current runtimes... maybe it is specific to my environment with Win10 V1809, that our current version controlled by our IT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found and tested two solutions:

- Install **.NET Core SDK** instead of **.NET Core Desktop Runtime**
   
  See https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0
- Deploy as self-contained app

**Select Publish**
[image: Publish project]

**Create Profile**
[image: Create Profile]

**Adjust Profile**
[image: Adjust Profile]

**Finally Publish**
[image: Finally Publish]